# Create subdirectory on Google Cloud Wordpress Installation on Virtual Machine

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Got Wordpress installed via Click-to-deploy using the marketplace from Google Cloud Platform.

The thing is: I would like to install it in the `/blog` folder, not in the `root` directory.

When trying to create a new folder using ssh connection it is returning an:

```
Access denied.
Error code: 3
Server error message: Permission denied
```

Can someone help me?

I need to install it in the `blog` folder so it can be accessed via `example.com/blog`, not in the `root` directory itself, which I will use to host another template.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create directories or files in the / directory you need root privileges.

Add `sudo` in front of your commands. Example: `sudo mkdir /blog`

You can also switch to a shell with privilege: `sudo -s`. Then you do not need to use `sudo` in front of each command.

Comment: I feel so dumb for not trying sudo before. lol 
Thanks @John Hanley